# Enabling SSL on tomcat using pem file

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

i Want to enable or configure https on my tomcat 8 server, This requires me to configure certificate paths. i have received .pem file, how do i use this .pem file to configure https on tomcat ?

Answer (score 6):

While most answers concentrate on versions 7.0 and 8.0 of Tomcat that were supported at the time of the question, since version 8.5.2 (May 2016) it is possible to use PEM files directly without conversion to a PKCS12 file.

You can either:

- put the PEM encoded private key and all certificates in the order from leaf to root into a single file (let's say `conf/cert.pem`) and use:

```xml
<Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" scheme="https">
  <SSLHostConfig>
    <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Storing both private key and certificate in the same file is highly **discouraged**.

- put the private key in `conf/privkey.pem` and the certificates (in the usual order) in `conf/cert.pem` and use:

```xml
<Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" scheme="https">
  <SSLHostConfig>
    <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                 certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

- use three separate files: e.g. `conf/privkey.pem` for the private key, `conf/cert.pem` for the server certificate and `conf/chain.pem` for the intermediary certificates and use:

```xml
<Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" scheme="https">
  <SSLHostConfig>
    <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                 certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
                 certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

This configuration is supported for all three connector types: `NIO`, `NIO2` and `APR`.

Comment: Are you sure all can be in single PEM file? Because Tomcat documentation mentions nothing about that for `certificateFile` ?
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen: Yes, you can check [this source code line](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8623d4becf96dce9c467600cc5791b3847e661f7/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLUtilBase.java#L314). `certificateFile` is the default value of `certificateKeyFile`.

Comment: Yes, manual says `certificateKeyFile` default value is the value of `certificateFile`. (also there is a warning saying "not recommended") But it does not talk anything about intermediate/chain. I think the code you pointed out also does not load `certificateChainFile` from `certificateFile` hmm?

Comment: The certificates found in `certificateChainFile` are appended to those in `certificateFile`. This way Tomcat supports the same configurations as [Apache Httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) and [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate). I added the remark about putting private and public key in the same file, thank you.

Comment: What I meant was that putting chain/intermediate certificates to `certificateFile` without using`certificateChainFile` does not seem to be supported. So the first option of putting everything into one file should not work?

Comment: I agree: options 1 and 2 are not explicitly documented, so they might stop working in a future release. However I doubt this will ever be the case: breaking configurations 1 and 2 might still be seen as a regression.

Comment: What I meant was, in the source code you linked. The chain file is only loaded if it is defined. `if (certificate.getCertificateChainFile() != null)` Maybe it works somehow... perhaps I should test it some day :)

Comment: Yes, the best option is to test it. The crucial part is that the code imports **all** certificates from `certificateFile` and **all** certificates in `certificateChainFile`. Where do you put a certificate does not matter, only the order matters.

Answer (score -2):

To enable `https` on your project, follow the steps below:

**1-** Go to your `JAVA_HOME` and run the following commmand: (Your directory of java may be different)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
  -keystore \path\to\your\directory\keystore.exe
```

It will take you through a process, and will ask a password for the `keystore.exe`. Remember this **password**.

**2-** At `\path\to\your\directory`, you should have your `keystore.exe`.

**3-** Now in your `apache tomcat's directory, open`server.xml` and write the following code:

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="9999" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
            keystoreFile="PATH_TO_YOUR_DIRECTORY/cert1.keystore" keystorePass="YOUR_PASSSWORD_HERE"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

**4-** Restart the server and open your project with `https` and port 9999. You will find your project on `https` now.

Answer (score -2):

If certificate files including Root, Intermediate and Primary certificate received in PEM format by Certificate Authority for your domain, then import certificate files into the Java Keystore using following command in keytool command line utility:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool” -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file RootCertFileName.crt -keystore keystore.key

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool” -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file IntermediateCertFileName.crt -keystore keystore.key

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool” keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file PrimaryCertFileName.crt -keystore keystore.key
```

**Note:** If you did not specify the alias during the keystore creation, the default value will be 'mykey'.

Upon executing commands successful, you will have .keystore file that needs to be copy to home directory. Now open Tomcat configuration file (server.xml) in text editor and locate the  element port is 8443. Specify keystoreFile and keystorePass as follows:

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.pem"
           SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
```

And, save your configuration file and Restart the server to enable SSL on Tomcat using .pem file.

You can follow instructions stated in the post: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html to enable SSL on Tomcat 8 server.

Comment: Config shown here references PEM files outside the keystore. Why import it the subject certificate into the keystore?